# Полосатая таблица

Tags: javascript, html, css

Нужно сделать полосатую таблицу. Все было бы довольно просто, но мою таблицу генерирует js с помощтю такого метода:

```
 $.getJSON('http://localhost/nop', function (data) {
    $("#numberOfAuct").html(data.length);

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {        
       $('#auctionFields').append('<tr><td>' + data[i].time + '</td><td>' + data[i].branch +
       '</td><td> Join Now ' + '<a href="Inventory/' + data[i].branch_code + '/1">1 </a>' + '<a href="Inventory/' + data[i].branch_code + '/2">2 </a>' + '<a href="Inventory/' + data[i].branch_code + '/3">3</a>' + '</td><td>' + data[i].branch_code + '</td><tr>');
    }
});
```

и генерирует он почему-то таблицу вида:

```
<tr><tr> <tr> information <tr> <tr><tr> <tr> information <tr> <tr><tr> <tr> information <tr>
```

тоесть пустые     tr     , потом       tr     с информацией и тд

Как мне сделать чтобы поля в таблице чередовали цвет или как убрать эти пустые поля?

Comment: Давайте исключим из вопроса сам аякс запрос и будем работать только с самими данными, которые он вернул.

Comment: Саму полосатость можно сделать через css `even/odd` https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html

Comment: я же описал что генерирует он лишную строку

Comment: По предоставленной вами информации невозможно определить, почему такое происходит. Вы уверены, что это единственный участок кода, который добавляет строки в данную таблицу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас ошибка при выводе строки. В конце должен быть закрывающийся `</tr>`, а у вас открывающийся. Пустые tr появляются вследствии попыток браузера исправить ошибки разметки. Если исправить так, то пустых строк не будет (если конечно в данных их нет)

```
$('#auctionFields').append('<tr><td>' + data[i].time + '</td><td>' + data[i].branch + '</td><td> Join Now ' + '<a href="Inventory/' + data[i].branch_code + '/1">1 </a>' +
'<a href="Inventory/' + data[i].branch_code + '/2">2 </a>' + '<a href="Inventory/' + data[i].branch_code + '/3">3</a>' + '</td><td>' + data[i].branch_code + '</td></tr>');
```

Comment: точно! спасибо! моя невнимательность =(